# Access - how to derive a field upon entry of a record

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database for a media rental company which includes the following tables, among others;

LOAN:
customer_id (pk),
loan_datetimeLeant (pk),
loan_dateReturned (pk)

LOAN_ITEMS:
customer_id (pk),
loan_datetimeLeant (pk),
item_id (pk),
loanItem_cost

ITEM:
item_id (pk),
product_id,
item_availability

PRODUCT:
product_id (pk),
product_name,
product_type

MEDIA_COST:
product_type (pk),
product_cost

So basically the 'product type' (DVD, VHS etc) determines the cost. The 'product id' determines what movie, platform etc each item is.

My question is:
When creating a form for the Loan_Items table, how can I populate the loanItem_cost field (so it is stored) whenever a new Loan_Item record is added? I need to store it as the cost of the item (product_cost) may change over time and I'd like to record what the customer paid at the time the loan was made.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, so now I have built a query that contains the 'product cost' and the 'loanItem_cost' (loanItem_cost values are empty). 
Then, I have created a form on that query which contains a button. Is there a way I can program that button so that when it is clicked it can populate the 'loanItem_cost' field with the 'product_cost' field?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the properties for the button and find the OnClick event.  Select Event Builder (or something like that, I'm just going from memory) and double-click.  This should take you into the code editor.  Here you can add something like `loanItem_cost = product_cost`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Default Value` property of the loanItem_cost form control to reference the product_cost from another form or from the product table.

If you have a form with a button that opens another form, you can reference a control on the parent form in the Default Value property: `Forms![ParentFormName]![product_cost]`.

Similarly, you can use a DLookup function:

```
DLookup("product_cost", "ProductTable", "product_id = " & Forms![ParentFormName]![product_id])
```

The source of the product_id value in the "where" parameter of the DLookup function can come from several places, but would likely be found on another form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an update query to update your `loan item cost` from the current `product cost`.  Then to perform the update, just execute the query.